# Why is the magnetic field proportional to distance?

Tags: electromagnetism

It's extremely difficult to create a magnetic field that can influence objects 1 m away, and somewhat impossible at 10 m away... Why is that? 
Why is the magnetic field heavily dependent on distance?

A solenoid, has $I$ flowing and generates $B$.

$B$ is only applied at small distances, by increasing $I$ to infinity(for example) would $B$ expand greatly over large distances? Or would that depend on $n$ of the solenoid?

Answer (score 5):

Because there are no magnetic charges the simplest system that can generate a magnetic field is a [dipole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole). The field from a dipole (magnetic or electric) falls off as $1/r^3$ rather than $1/r^2$ so the field strength falls off more rapidly with distance than the electric field from a point charge.

Increasing the current or the number of turns will certainly increase the strength of the magnetic field from a solenoid, but you're still stuck with the $1/r^3$ dependance on distance. You might be interested in [this article](http://www.technologyreview.com/view/514201/physicists-build-worlds-first-magnetic-hose-for-transmitting-magnetic-fields/) that describes one way of channeling a magnetic field over (relatively) large distances.

Comment: I read it earlier when you posted it on another question, but the thing is how can this be useful? Could this be used to attract objects from point X to the magnetic source? I doubt the usefulness of this concept, probably from my lack on understanding.

Comment: @key: it could be used to attract objects to the end of the magnetic pipe. Once the object hit the end of the pipe it would be stuck there - it wouldn't travel down the pipe towards the magnet.

Comment: Do you think it's possible to build electromagnet that produces a magnetic field that could apply forces of 1000N+ over 0.101 meters?  If so, how massive might it be and how much power do you think it would consume?

Comment: @Key: I have no idea I'm afraid.